# How to add particles on the surface of a mesh with Solidify modifier?

Tags: modifiers, particles

I am a beginner in Blender and whenever I try to put particles on a surface, they seem to be embedded within the mesh. I am making a model of a cake and the top chocolate layer has a solidify modifier. I was thinking of placing small chocolate flakes on top of the icing of the cake but the flakes rather than appearing on the surface of the icing are embedded within it and can only be viewed if their scale is increased (which obviously, creates a horrendous effect).
Is there a solution to this problem? If there is can anyone please help me out and please do elaborate as I'm a total beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the particle system is placed last in the modifier stack (the bottom most one) :

[image]

And also check "Use modifier stack" in the source panel of the particle settings :

[image]